# display array of json objects using handlebar in nodejs & express

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm new to node and trying to retrieve data from mongodb and display it to the client.I'm using handlebars for this purpose.I'm retrieving data from mongo collection it's an array of json objects but not successfully display it in html.
Here is my code snippets :
Retrieving from mongodb:

```
usrRouter.route('/profile/projects')
    .get(function(req,res){
            project.find({pusername:userN},function (err,projects) {
                if(err){console.log(err); }
                else{
                    res.render('projects',{"project":projects})
                }
            });

    });
```

It's Results:
[Take a look on screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJdoM.png)

Html Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Project Name</th>
                        <th>Project Type</th>
                        <th>Project Description</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {{#each project}}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{projectName}} </td>
                    <td> {{projectType}} </td>
                    <td> {{projectDesc}} </td>
                    <td> <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                         <span> <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Download</button>
                         </span> </td>
                </tr>
                            {{/each}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Is there an error in the server side or browser console? How is the HTML rendered? The code is looking fine.

Comment: Here is renderd html :                                                                             `<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
 <td></td>
 <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
 <span> <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Download</button>
</span> </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td>  </td>
<td> <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
<span> <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Download</button>
</span> </td>
</tr>
    </tbody>`

Comment: So the variable's are rendered like they would be empty. That's exactly what happens if you have no value in those properties, or if those properties don't exist at all. Check the contents of your projects variable before calling res.render. Which Handlebars Node module are you using? There are different ones.

Comment: no of <td>'s has been generated according to the numbers of records in array but doesn't display any data in these <td>'s, help me please!

Comment: I'm using " express-handlebars " module.

Comment: You could try this one https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs If it doesn't work with that one, problems with your data from the database is my only idea.